# PDO - SQL COUNT not working in PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm working on a website, where I wish to use an SQL query to count the number of times the logged in user's ID is displayed in a database table. In order to achieve this, I have created a PHP function, containing the SQL query.

**PHP Function:**

```
function count_by_user_id() {
     global $conn, $counts;
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS `returnCount` FROM `table` WHERE `user_id` = :id;");

     $stmt->execute([
         ":id" => $_SESSION["user_id"]
     ]);

     $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
     $counts["returnCount"] = $data["returnCount"];
}
```

The returned result should be stored in a variable called `$counts["returnCount"]`, which is then displayed on another page, called `count.php`.

**count.php**

```
<div class="data"><?=htmlspecialchars($counts["returnCount"]); ?></div>
```

Unfortunately, nothing is displayed on `count.php`, and I can't seem to work out why.

So my question is, how do I count the number of times `user_id` appears in `table`, and display that result on `count.php`?

Comment: Is `$data` populated?

Comment: @chris85, I'm assuming so - my other SQL queries are working fine, and are displayed on `count.php`, using PDO. It just seems to be the COUNT query which is causing problems for me.

Comment: Check, try `print_r($data);`.

Comment: @chris85, I've just tried using your suggested code, and it would appear as though `$data` is not populated.

Comment: Any error message returned? Does the query work directly on DB?

Comment: @chris85, no error returned, and the query works directly on the database

Comment: Is `$_SESSION["user_id"]` populated, and/or the same value as the one you tested the DB with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82407/discussion-between-tim-and-chris85).

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

As I understand the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchcolumn-returnvalues):

> **PDOStatement::fetchColumn()** returns a single column in the *next* row of a result set.

`PDOStatement::fetchColumn()` returns the data of one column of one (namely the *next*) row.

So after `$data = $stmt->fetchColumn();`, `$data` should contain the value already. This means that `$user["returnCount"] = $data;` should do the trick.

Maybe you want to change the way you fetch data to [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).
Then your code would look like this:

```
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$user["returnCount"] = $data["returnCount"];
```

Notice: This answer refers to the first version of the question.

Comment: @user2586348 Looks like you have at least one other error. You should use a debugger and error-reporting, get the actual error message and update your question.